# Removing Lines in php ? Is this possible?

Tags: php, file-io

I have been struggling to create a Simple ( really simple ) chat system for my website as my knowledge on Javascripting/AJAX are Limited after gather resources and help from many kind people I was able to create my simple chat system but left with one problem.

The messages are posted to a file called "msg.html" in this format :
`<p><span id="name">$name</span><span id="Msg">$message</span></p>`
And then using PHP and AJAX I will retrieve the messages instantly from the file using the 
file(); function and a foreach(){} loop withing PHP here is the code :

```
    <?php 
$file = 'msg.html';
$data = file($file);
$max_lines = 20;
if(count($data) > $max_lines){
    // here i want the data to be deleted from oldest until i only have 20 messages left.
}
foreach($data as $line_num => $line){
echo $line_num . " . " . $line; 
}
?>
```

My Question is how can i delete the oldest messages so that i am only left with the latest 20 Messages ?

Comment: You really should be using a database, such as MySQL, as a plain file-based approach is a very poor approach for this task.

Comment: Do you have a database available? Doing this kind of stuff with text files (in a reliable way) is utterly complicated.

Comment: He should actually be using some sort of socket based solution, not MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does something like this seem to you:

```
$file = 'msg.html';
$data = file($file);
$max_lines = 20;
foreach($data as $line_num => $line)
{
    if ($line_num < $max_lines)
    {
        echo $line_num . " . " . $line; 
    }
    else
    {
        unset($data[$line_num]);
    }
}
file_put_contents('msg.html', $data);
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php for more info :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked =) feeling stupid not thinking of that

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can read the file, explode it into an array, chop off everything but last 20 fields and write it back to file, overwriting the old one... Perhaps not the best solution but one that comes to mind if you really cant use database as Delan suggested

Answer (score 0):

That's called round-robin if I recall correctly.

As far as I know, you can't remove arbitrary portions of a file. You need to overwrite the file with the new contents (or create a new file and remove the old one). You could also store messages in individual files but of course that implies up to `$max_lines` files to read.

You should also use [flock()](http://php.net/flock) to avoid data corruption. Depending on the platform it's not 100% reliable but it's better than nothing.